# "Assailant" vs "Attacker"

Tags: differences, nouns, connotation

Besides sports in which an attacker is an offensive player, is there any difference between *[assailant](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/assailant)* and *[attacker](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/attacker)*?

> a person who attacks somebody

I guess *attacker* can also be used for animals but not *assailant*. Is there anything else or are they fully interchangeable when describing a person who physically attacks somebody else?

Can both words also be used when talking about psychological attacks, like insulting, bullying, etc?

Comment: I think you meant *psychological*.  I edited.

Comment: Did you consult a dictionary?  You seem to have left that part out of your research.

Comment: @Danielδ Thanks for edit. That's what I meant. .. And sure I checked a dictionary but both just said: "A person who attacks somebody"

Comment: For the sake of completeness I added the notes of my favorite dictionary, but actually it should be obvious that I did some research otherwise I would had forgotten sports and also wasn't aware that only attacker can be used for animals (at least that's what my research told me, still may be wrong)...

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the two words are used interchangeably, especially when referring to the act of physically setting upon a person.

To trace the difference between them,  we take a look at their Verbs:

"[Assail](http://www.univsource.com/words/assail-verb.htm)" means:

> to attack a person violently to cause hurt to them. The attack may be
>   physical or verbal. When you assail a person (verbally), you **abuse**
>   them. Assailing consists in hitting a person very hard and repeatedly.

"[Attack](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/attack)" means:

> to set upon with violence and applies to offensive action, especially
>   to the onset of planned aggression. It also means to **criticize**
>   strongly in a hostile manner.

Answer (score 2):

*Assailant* comes from the same root as *assault*, which has connotations beyond just *attack*.  At one time, newspapers were not allowed to use the word *sexual*, which led to overuse of *assault* in reporting rapes.  There is an alleged news story (much too good to check) along the lines of 'The woman was grabbed from behind, overpowered, and left bleeding and unconscious.  She was fortunate not to have been assaulted.'

Comment: Interesting hint. I conjecture that *assailant* is still preferred when talking about sexual attacks rather than *attacker*?

Answer (score 0):

OED definitions suggest the two are synonymous. However, *attacker* is nearly five times as frequent in the British National Corpus and nearly twice as frequent in the Corpus of Contemporary American English. A corpus search might uncover differences of use, perhaps showing, for example, that *assailant* was used more in legal contexts.