# Is "assaulter" a proper English term?

Tags: word-usage

In light of recent events in the States, there were controversial discussions about the use of the word "rape" and "sexual assault". I know for a fact that "rapist" is the correct term to describe one who performed the act of rape but for the latter term, is "sexual assaulter" a correct English term? For me, it just sounds weird. I was thinking that maybe "sexual assailant" is the proper term given that both "assault" and "assail" comes from a common Latin root word *assilire* but I am not sure.

Comment: It's not incorrect, but *assailant* would be preferred.

Comment: I don't disagree with you but when you wrote "preferred", to whom is it preferred? I asked a foreign friend and he said *assailant* sounded more strange.

Comment: To a native US English speaker *assailant* would sound more natural.

Comment: *Assailant* would sound more natural to a native British English speaker.

Comment: Related: [*Assailant* vs *attacker*](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/74484/8019).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both *assaulter* and *assailant* are correct and are synonyms (see http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/assailant).

However, *assailant* is much more widely used:

[image: Google NGrams screenshot, assaulter vs assailant]

Answer (score 1):

Lists of *synonyms* for **assailant** from various dictionaries:

> attacker, assaulter, bushwhacker — [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/assailant) (US)
>
> attacker, mugger, assaulter, attack dog — [Oxford Dictionary Online - American English](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english-thesaurus/assailant)
>
> attacker, mugger, *rare* assaulter — [Oxford Dictionary Online - British & World English](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english-thesaurus/assailant#assailant__1)
>
> attacker, invader, opponent, adversary, enemy, mugger, aggressor, assailer, assaulter, abuser, reviler — [Chambers](http://www.chambers.co.uk/search.php?query=assailant&title=21st#) (UK)

This tends to support the answer from @HerbCaudill that **assaulter** and **assailant** are both correct and are synonyms.  It also suggests that **assaulter** is more rare in British English than in American English.

As an aside, it also suggests that there are some American alternatives not used in the UK:

- **bushwhacker** is a term I'm aware of, but I thought it just referred to someone who spent a lot of time in 'the bush'
- **attack dog** is a term I assumed just referred to a dog!

Comment: "Attack dog" is often applied to a hired thug.